# Getting duplicate key error but unique attribute is not set in a collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a below mongoose schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  employeeID: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  reviewID: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Some', SomeSchema);
```

As you can see that non of the above attributes are required to be unique. However, when I save a new entry with employeeID already exist in the db I get duplicate key error below.

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: paypay.participants index: employeeID_1 dup key: { employeeID: "60d453f5b2b39db9453cdc18" }
```

Here is how I save to this db.

```
new Some({
                              employeeID: employeeID, // this is fine too no error here.
                              reviewID: reviewID, // reviewID exist this is fine no error here.
                              email: email, // this is fine too no error here.
                            })
                            .save()
                            .then(doc => {
                              if (doc) {
                                response.json({
                                  message: `employee is added as participant to this review.`,
                                });
                              } else {
                                response.json({
                                  message: 'There is a problem adding participant in database.',
                                });
                              }
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                              response.json(error);
                            });
```

Comment: I ran into this a few years ago, I ended up implementing `upsert`  instead of `save` whenever creating records that rapid fired

Comment: probably there is already created a unique index in `employeeID` field, just check in your database using [getIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/) command, and if you found index in list you can remove it by [dropIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) command.

Comment: Execute `syncIndexes` in mongoose to make the mongodb indexes match the schema

Comment: did you had `employeeID` as unique initially and then changed it ?

Comment: @alilland how can I use `upsert`? Can you post an example? I checked online and it is used with `findOneAndUpdate` function.

Comment: @Joe I also tried `syncIndexes` however, it says `.syncIndexes is not a function`. Any idea how to use it? I used like `Model.syncIndexes()`before the `save()` function on a Model.

Comment: @Om3ga `findOneAndUpdate` is correct